# How to get conditional columns by joining two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables.One is product table another is shipping table.

```
Product
-------
ProductID   ProductName
1           Test1
2           Test2
Shipping
--------
ProductID   ShippingOption  Cost
1           Ground          0
1           SecondDay       100
1           OverNight       200
2           Ground          0
2           SecondDay       110
```

Now I want to create a report like

```
 Productid  IsGround    GroundCost  IsSecondDay SecondDayCost   IsOvernight OvernightCost
 1            1           0            1          100            1           200
 2            1           0            1          110            0           NULL
```

I have tried using join but actually can not understand how to proceed. Please help I am new to writing sql query.

Comment: Google "sql server pivot".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
select ProductID,
sum(case when ShippingOption='Ground' then 1 else 0 end) ISGrouped,
sum(case when ShippingOption='Ground' then  Cost else 0 end) GroupCost,
sum(case when ShippingOption='SecondDay' then 1 else 0 end) ISSecondDay,
sum(case when ShippingOption='SecondDay' then  Cost else 0 end) SecondDayCost,
sum(case when ShippingOption='OverNight' then 1 else 0 end)ISOverNight,
sum(case when ShippingOption='OverNight' then  Cost else 0 end)
OverNightCost from Shipping group by ProductID
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4344e/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to provide users with the report which should look like  this, then the best bet is "matrix report" (at least it's called as such in SSRS). It will do all the pivoting for you in a much more expandable manner than any kind of SQL query.